# Solve a system of non-linear equations in Python (scipy.optimize.fsolve)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to solve the following simple system of non-linear equations ([Source(second example)](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/systems-linear-quadratic-equations.html)):

```
(I) y - x^2 = 7 - 5x
(II) 4y - 8x = -21
```

which should have only one solution (x=3.5, y=1.75).

My current approach using the [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve) stack is the following:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return (y - x**2 -7 + 5*x, 4*y - 8*x + 21)

x, y =  fsolve(equations, (5, 5))

print(equations((x, y)))
```

and yields the following (which is not the result):

```
(0.0, 0.0)
```

I have already tried different starting estimates but it doesn't deliver the right  solution.

What's wrong with my approach? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works perfectly fine:

```
In [1]: %paste
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return (y - x**2 -7 + 5*x, 4*y - 8*x + 21)

x, y =  fsolve(equations, (5, 5))

print(equations((x, y)))

## -- End pasted text --
(0.0, 0.0)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: 3.5000000414181831

In [3]: y
Out[3]: 1.7500000828363667
```

`equations(x, y)` being `(0, 0)` means that both  `y - x**2 -7 + 5*x`  and `4*y - 8*x + 21` are 0.

Maybe you got confused and meant to `print(x, y)` instead of `print(equations(x, y))` ?