# Error solving a system of non linear equation using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to solve this system of non linear equations using scipy.optimize.fsolve , I took this from an example in one other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783190/solve-a-system-of-non-linear-equations-in-python-scipy-optimize-fsolve)

my system of equation is the follow :

```
for i in range(len(self.time)-1):

            def equations(variable):
                k1,k2 = variable 
                f1 = -k1 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2) 
                f2 = -k2 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)
                return (f1,f2)


            k1,k2 = fsolve(equations,(5,5))
```

when I run the code I got :

```
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'equations'.Shape should be (2,) but it is (2, 1).
```

**EDIT** I don't know why this mismatch and how to fix it ..
I tried :

```
for i in range(len(self.time)-1):
            ui = self.u[i]
            ti = self.time[i]

            def equations(variable):
                k1,k2 = variable 
                f1 = -k1 + self.f(ti+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , ui+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2) 
                f2 = -k2 + self.f(ti+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , ui+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)
                return (f1,f2)


            k1,k2 = fsolve(equations,(1,1))
```

**EDIT** 
I've tried :  `return np.array([f1,f2])` 
and I got the same mismatch error!

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: In which way ? may you give me an hint please ?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
We don't understand where you are stuck: the error message clearly states the conflicting tensor shapes -- `equations` vs `(5,5)`.

Comment: yes I see, but my variable is just K1 and k2 !! I don't get the point ...

Comment: right I understand the bug .. but I don't know how to fix it !

Comment: same error that i got before using `return np.array([f1,f2])`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is here:

> Shape should be (2,) but it is (2, 1).

Even if you have just two values, in numpy it is different to have an "unidimensional vector" with two values, and a "bidimensional matrix" with two values.

I suggest that you call `ravel()` or `flatten()` to convert your `(2,1)` shape to a `(2,)` shape:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2]])

print("before:")
print("array: ", a)
print("shape: ", a.shape)
print()

b = a.ravel()

print("after:")
print("array: ", b)
print("shape: ", b.shape)

> before:
> array:  [[1 2]]
> shape:  (1, 2)

> after:
> array:  [1 2]
> shape:  (2,)
```

Comment: can you give me an example ? because I have problem ... I'm going to explain : some times I use the self.u[i] not like single array but multiple array .. and for example in this case i got this : `TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'equations'.Shape should be (2,) but it is (2, 2).` what you suggest me ?

Comment: Looks like you solved the problem using `reshape()`, which does a similar thing to `ravel()`...

Comment: no I don't ... because this equations is also used for the system ! and it give me :`TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'equations'.Shape should be (2,) but it is (4,).`

Comment: I mean self.u[i] is shape 2,1