# How to solve a system of nonlinear equations with multiplication of unknown members in Python?

Tags: numpy, math, scipy

I have following system of nonlinear equations:

[image]

This is very similar to Cholesky’s decomposition, but unfortunately it’s not it.

I have found very familiar solution: [Solve a system of non-linear equations in Python (scipy.optimize.fsolve)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783190/solve-a-system-of-non-linear-equations-in-python-scipy-optimize-fsolve) but I don't know how to dynamically setup all equations of my system.

How to solve this system within Numpy, Scipy or any other packages in Python?

Comment: Hmm, it's an interesting problem. Do you need a symbolic solution or a numerical solution? (For what purpose are you solving this problem?) For what values of N are you interested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SymPy is the package that you're looking for.](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) Here is a function that dynamically sets up your equations as described in your system:

```
import sympy as sp

def not_choleskys_decomposition(N):
    # Initialisation of list of variables.
    c = []
    K = []
    for n in range(N + 1):
        c.append(sp.Symbol("c_{}".format(n), real=True))
        K.append(sp.Symbol("K_{}".format(n), real=True))

    # Setup your N+1 equations.
    equations = []
    for n in range(N + 1):
        num_c = N + 1 - n
        c_terms = [c_i * c_j for c_i, c_j in zip(c[:num_c], c[n:][:num_c])]
        lhs = sp.Add(*c_terms)
        equations.append(sp.Eq(lhs, K[n]))
    return equations, c, K
```

**Printing for verification** can be done using the `sympy.latex` function which converts the math directly to LaTeX or the `sympy.pprint` function.

```
>>> test, _, _ = not_choleskys_decomposition(4)
>>> for t in test:
...    sp.pprint(t)

c₀⋅c₀ + c₁⋅c₁ + c₂⋅c₂ + c₃⋅c₃ + c₄⋅c₄ = K₀
c₀⋅c₁ + c₁⋅c₂ + c₂⋅c₃ + c₃⋅c₄ = K₁
c₀⋅c₂ + c₁⋅c₃ + c₂⋅c₄ = K₂
c₀⋅c₃ + c₁⋅c₄ = K₃
c₀⋅c₄ = K₄
```

**Replacing your variables** can be done with the `.subs` method which belongs to each `sympy.Eq` object:

```
>>> equations, c_sym, K_sym = not_choleskys_decomposition(4)
>>> dict_replace = {c_sym[0]: 1.0}
>>> new_equation = equations[0].subs(dict_replace)
>>> sympy.pprint(new_equation)

c₁⋅c₂ + 1.0⋅c₁ + c₂⋅c₃ + c₃⋅c₄ = K₁
```

**Here's an example function that replaces** your list of `c` or `K`.

```
def substitute_sym(equations, sym_list, val_list):
    # Confirm all dimensions are consistent.
    try:
        assert len(equations) == len(sym_list) == len(val_list)
    except AssertionError:
        raise IndexError("Inconsistent dimensions.")

    # Replace c symbols with values in equations.
    substituted_equations = []
    for eq in equations:
        _eq = eq.subs(dict(zip(sym_list, val_list)))
        substituted_equations.append(_eq)

    return substituted_equations
```

*Testing it on `c`*:

```
>>> equations, c_sym, K_sym = not_choleskys_decomposition(4)
>>> test_2 = substitute_sym(test_1, c_sym, [1] * 5)
>>> for t in test_2:
...    sp.pprint(t)

5 = K₀
4 = K₁
3 = K₂
2 = K₃
1 = K₄
```

*Testing it on `K`*:

```
>>> equations, c_sym, K_sym = not_choleskys_decomposition(4)
>>> K_vals = [1, 1.4, 0.2, 0.5, 3.0]
>>> test_3 = substitute_sym(test_1, K_sym, K_vals)
>>> for t in test_3:
...    sp.pprint(t)

c₀⋅c₀ + c₁⋅c₁ + c₂⋅c₂ + c₃⋅c₃ + c₄⋅c₄ = 1
c₀⋅c₁ + c₁⋅c₂ + c₂⋅c₃ + c₃⋅c₄ = 1.4
c₀⋅c₂ + c₁⋅c₃ + c₂⋅c₄ = 0.2
c₀⋅c₃ + c₁⋅c₄ = 0.5
c₀⋅c₄ = 3.0
```

**Solving your set of equation** can be done with `sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve(system, *symbols)` [documented here.](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve)

*Solving for `c` given `K`*

```
>>> from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve
>>> test_solve, c_sym, K_sym = not_choleskys_decomposition(1)
>>> test_replaced = substitute_sym(test_solve, K_sym, [sp.Rational(0.5)] * 2)
>>> solved = nonlinsolve(test_replaced, c_sym)
>>> sp.pprint(solved)

⎧⎛ ⎛                    2⎞                           ⎞  ⎛ ⎛                   
⎪⎜ ⎜       ⎛  √6   √2⋅ⅈ⎞ ⎟ ⎛  √6   √2⋅ⅈ⎞    √6   √2⋅ⅈ⎟  ⎜ ⎜       ⎛  √6   √2⋅ⅈ
⎨⎜-⎜-1 + 2⋅⎜- ── - ────⎟ ⎟⋅⎜- ── - ────⎟, - ── - ────⎟, ⎜-⎜-1 + 2⋅⎜- ── + ────
⎪⎝ ⎝       ⎝  4     4  ⎠ ⎠ ⎝  4     4  ⎠    4     4  ⎠  ⎝ ⎝       ⎝  4     4  
⎩                                                                             

 2⎞                           ⎞  ⎛ ⎛                  2⎞                      
⎞ ⎟ ⎛  √6   √2⋅ⅈ⎞    √6   √2⋅ⅈ⎟  ⎜ ⎜       ⎛√6   √2⋅ⅈ⎞ ⎟ ⎛√6   √2⋅ⅈ⎞  √6   √2⋅
⎟ ⎟⋅⎜- ── + ────⎟, - ── + ────⎟, ⎜-⎜-1 + 2⋅⎜── - ────⎟ ⎟⋅⎜── - ────⎟, ── - ───
⎠ ⎠ ⎝  4     4  ⎠    4     4  ⎠  ⎝ ⎝       ⎝4     4  ⎠ ⎠ ⎝4     4  ⎠  4     4 


 ⎞  ⎛ ⎛                  2⎞                       ⎞⎫
ⅈ⎟  ⎜ ⎜       ⎛√6   √2⋅ⅈ⎞ ⎟ ⎛√6   √2⋅ⅈ⎞  √6   √2⋅ⅈ⎟⎪
─⎟, ⎜-⎜-1 + 2⋅⎜── + ────⎟ ⎟⋅⎜── + ────⎟, ── + ────⎟⎬
 ⎠  ⎝ ⎝       ⎝4     4  ⎠ ⎠ ⎝4     4  ⎠  4     4  ⎠⎪
                                                   ⎭
```

I hope this helps get you jump started with `SymPy` if you choose to use it. I have rarely used its nonlinear solver so I cannot guarantee anything past the examples. Arguments are also relevant and solvers are temperamental. You'll notice I replaced `K` with `sp.Rational(0.5)` for each index. It was done to avoid an error that is thrown otherwise when defining `float` type for some solvers. Good luck.

EDIT:

Also note that you don't need to use the solvers in SymPy. I rarely do. I use the package for the symbolic mathematics in Python for LaTeX and equation manipulation.

EDIT:

**Making it work with `scipy.optimize.fsolve`**

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def lambdify_equations_for_solving_c(equations, c_sym, K_sym, K_val):
    f = []
    equations_subbed = substitute_sym(equations, K_sym, K_val)
    for eq in equations_subbed:
        # Note that I reformulate equation into an expression here
        # for determining the roots.
        f.append(lambdify(c_sym, eq.args[0] - eq.args[1]))
    return f


N = 4
equations, c_sym, K_sym = not_choleskys_decomposition(N)
K_vals = [0.1, 0, 0.1, 0, 0]
f = lambdify_equations_for_solving_c(equations, c_sym, K_sym, K_vals)

def fsolve_friendly(p):
    return [_f(*p) for _f in f]

c_sol = fsolve(fsolve_friendly, x0=(0, 0.1, -1.1, 0, 0))
```

`fsolve` returns warnings for non-converged results.

```
/home/ggarrett/anaconda3/envs/sigh/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:162: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

That's a complete answer on how to form your equations to be solved as python callables. The solver routine is another challenge itself.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. The equations are a polynomial system and so I wonder if the business about the unsolvability of general polynomials of degree 5 or greater in terms of radicals will come into play. Maybe it can be shown that in this particular case, there is indeed a solution for all N, but I guess I would suggest that question be studied first before searching for a symbolic solution.

Comment: Apologies for my imbalanced answer. I was more focused on helping the OP create the set of equations. I'm adding more to my answer that allows for it to be made into a function, and used with fsolve. The results aren't promising from fsolve, but it's the most complete assistance I can give regarding the programming - the mathematical is another.